# What is the correct way to code this in Swift / SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

My apologies. It was never my intent to upset anyone.

"What is this? Please describe what the code is supposed to do –
vadian"

This code is supposed to help me learn making an app in the Apple world (iOS, MacOS, whatever).

"If you forgive the observation, in the future you should give your question a title that explains what you are trying to do or what the problem is. See How do I ask a good question? which includes suggestions about good titles. –
Rob"

Very sorry on this point. This is where my stupidity shines. I thought the question title was clear enough, and the answer I got seems like an exact answer to it.

If you forgive my observation, if you would please post what would be a good question title, then maybe I would understand, if I should need to post again in the future, which at this point, I would be afraid of the hate.

What I am trying to do is learn to make Apps.

The problem is that I have very limited time borrowing a new Mac Pro from a friend and am trying to learn to make Apps, and Swift, etc. It's quite a different world than Z80 Assembly and C. I do program in C++ and BASH nowadays but in simplistic ways.

What would have been a good question title? Please tell me.
Or should I have made several posts with the same source code and a different question? I had about 5 to 10 questions, and thought it simpler just to ask for the correct code.

Anyway, thanks to the person answering the question, it is perfect!

I wanted to just delete this rather than a long response, but then it wouldn't let me. Therefore this long explanation.

This does not need to be "reopened". Just responding before my account gets deleted.

---

(original post...)

I will greatly appreciate any info..

The current way I am doing this is not updating the screen properly. It is always a screen too late, and such.

The effort in the block comment works, but takes up space on screen, and that gets to be a problem as well is not the intention.

Just starting to learn this.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CoinFlip: View {
    
    @State var SaveFailed: Bool = false
    @State var flipResult: Bool = false
    @State var justFlipped: Bool = false
    @State var flipCount = 0
    @State var headsCount = 0
    @State var percentHeads : Float = 0

     func test1 () {
         flipCount = 0
         headsCount = 0
         for bob in flippedCoins {
         if bob.wasHeads {
             headsCount += 1; flipCount += 1; percentHeads = (Float(headsCount) / Float(flipCount)) * 100
         }
         else { flipCount += 1; percentHeads = (Float(headsCount) / Float(flipCount)) * 100
         }
         }
     }

    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var coinFlipHistory
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FlippedCoin.timeStamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    var flippedCoins: FetchedResults<FlippedCoin>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: addItem) {
                Label("Flip", systemImage: "plus")
            }
            //.onAppear(perform: test1)
            Button(action: eraseHistory) {
                Label("Erase History", systemImage: "minus")
            }
            Spacer()
            if ( justFlipped ) {
                if ( flipResult ) {
                    Text("You flipped heads!")
                }
                else {
                    Text("You flipped tales!")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
//            .onAppear(perform: test1)
            switch flipCount {
            case 0:
                Text("No coin has been flipped.")
            case 1:
                Text("You have flipped a coin only one time.")
                Text("")
                if ( headsCount > 0 )
                {
                    Text("It was heads.")
                }
                else
                {
                    Text("It was tails.")
                }
            default:
                Text("Coins have been flipped \(flipCount) times.")
                Text("")
                Text("\(Int(percentHeads)) % heads.")
            }
            /*
            HStack {
                ForEach(flippedCoins) { item in
  //                      Text("Flipped at \(item.timeStamp!, formatter: itemFormatter) ")
 //                                              .onAppear() { flipCount += 1 }
                    if item.wasHeads {
                        Text("")
                            .onAppear() { headsCount += 1; flipCount += 1; percentHeads = (Float(headsCount) / Float(flipCount)) * 100 }
                    }
                    else {
                        Text("")
                            .onAppear() { flipCount += 1; percentHeads = (Float(headsCount) / Float(flipCount)) * 100 }
                    }
                }
            }
             */
            Text("")
                .onAppear(perform: test1)
            if ( SaveFailed ) {
                Text ("HA HA!")
                Text ("Something went wrong.")
                Text ("")
                Text ("Your flips were not saved! Too bad.")
                
            }
        }
//        .onAppear(perform: test1)
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
            let rndMin = 0
            let rndMax = 1000
            let randRoll: Int = Int.random(in: rndMin...rndMax)
            flipResult = randRoll >= 500
            let newItem = FlippedCoin(context: coinFlipHistory)
            newItem.timeStamp = Date()
            newItem.wasHeads = flipResult
            newItem.rndMinimun = Int16(rndMin)
            newItem.rndMaximum = Int16(rndMax)
            newItem.rndValue = Int16(randRoll)
            justFlipped = true
            test1 ()

            do {
                try coinFlipHistory.save()
            } catch {
                SaveFailed = true;
            }

    }
    
    private func eraseHistory() {

            flippedCoins.forEach(coinFlipHistory.delete)
            
            justFlipped = false
            flipCount = 0
            headsCount = 0
            do {
                try coinFlipHistory.save()
            } catch {
                SaveFailed = true;
            }
    }
}


private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()
    
struct CoinFlip_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CoinFlip()
    }
}
```

I've thought of a number of things, but couldn't get the syntax right, even if it was the right thing.

I've tried Xcodes help looking things up and stuff, and am not getting very far.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is *this*? Please describe what the code is supposed to do

Comment: If you forgive the observation, in the future you should give your question a title that explains what you are trying to do or what the problem is. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which includes suggestions about good titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When coding you want to focus on a single source of truth. You are using CoreData to save the history so you should get all your data from there.

`flipCount`, `headsCount`, and `percentHeads` can be computed properties so you don't have to manually maintain a second source for all those numbers.

You can also have a computed property for the `latest` flip, so you can display all the details or delete one by one in reverse order.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CoinFlip: View {
    
    @State var saveFailed: Bool = false
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var coinFlipHistory
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FlippedCoin.timeStamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    var flippedCoins: FetchedResults<FlippedCoin>
    
    var latest: FlippedCoin?{
        flippedCoins.last
    }
    
    var flipCount: Int{
        flippedCoins.count
    }
    var headsCount: Int{
        flippedCoins.filter { coin in
            coin.wasHeads
        }.count
    }
    var percentHeads: Int{
        Int((Double(headsCount) / Double(flipCount)) * 100)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: addItem) {
                Label("Flip", systemImage: "plus")
            }
            Button(action: eraseHistory) {
                Label("Erase History", systemImage: "minus")
            }
            Spacer()
            
            if let latest = latest {
                if latest.wasHeads {
                    Text("You flipped heads!")
                }
                else {
                    Text("You flipped tales!")
                }
                
                Text(latest.rndValue, format: .number)
            }
            Spacer()
            switch flipCount {
            case 0:
                Text("No coin has been flipped.")
            case 1:
                Text("You have flipped a coin only one time.")
                Text("")
                if let latest = latest, latest.wasHeads{
                    Text("It was heads.")
                } else {
                    Text("It was tails.")
                }
            default:
                Text("Coins have been flipped \(flipCount) times.")
                Text("")
                Text("\(percentHeads.formatted(.percent)) heads.")
            }
            ForEach(flippedCoins, id:\.id) { item in
                HStack{
                    Text("Flipped at \(item.timeStamp!, formatter: itemFormatter) ")
                    Text(item.wasHeads ? "Heads" : "Tails")
                }
            }
            
            if ( saveFailed ) {
                Text ("HA HA!")
                Text ("Something went wrong.")
                Text ("")
                Text ("Your flips were not saved! Too bad.")
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        print(#function)
        
        let rndMin = 0
        let rndMax = 1000
        let randRoll: Int = Int.random(in: rndMin...rndMax)
        let newItem = FlippedCoin(context: coinFlipHistory)
        newItem.timeStamp = Date()
        newItem.wasHeads = randRoll >= 500
        newItem.rndMinimun = Int16(rndMin)
        newItem.rndMaximum = Int16(rndMax)
        newItem.rndValue = Int16(randRoll)
        do {
            try coinFlipHistory.save()
        } catch {
            saveFailed = true;
        }
        
    }
    
    private func eraseHistory() {
        
        //Use this code to clear all
        //            for item in flippedCoins{
        //                coinFlipHistory.delete(item)
        //            }
        
        
        //Use this code to clear one at a time
        if let latest = latest{
            coinFlipHistory.delete(latest)
        }
        do {
            try coinFlipHistory.save()
        } catch {
            saveFailed = true;
        }
    }
}

struct CoinFlip_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CoinFlip().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()
```